# assert list string having URL contains sub-string using C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to assert list of string that contains URL extracted from href attributes of elements using Selenium C#. Below is my code and when i am running its given false.

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<string> urlList = new List<string>();

    // Adding elements to List
    urlList.Add("https://www.google.com");
    urlList.Add("/app/facebook");
    urlList.Add("https://www.gmail.com");
        
    // Checking whether string is present
    // in List or not
    Console.Write(urlList.Contains("google"));
    }
```

OUTPUT: False

Comment: `urlList.Contains` checks if one of the items in `urlList` is the `string` `"google"`. That's it. You have to loop through (either indirectly using LINQ or by writing the loop yourself) if you want to check if the strings in the list contain a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
Console.Write(urlList.Any(x => x.Contains("google")));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `Any` Operator which is used to check whether at least one of the elements of a data source satisfies a given condition or not.

```
 public static void Main()
 {
    List<string> urlList = new List<string>();
    urlList.Add("https://www.google.com");
    urlList.Add("/app/facebook");
    urlList.Add("https://www.gmail.com");
        
    bool isContains = urlList.Any(x => x.Contains("google"));
 }
```

More about `Any` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-6.0